Max number of characters in schema definiton for inline-transfer of CLOBs
I've written a TPT job script that transfers data from a DB2 table to Teradata via ODBC.
There are CLOB fields in the source table, which I also want to transfer. When I don't define a length for the CLOB columns, TPT creates temporary files for the CLOB columns while the job is running. This seems to take a long time.
DEFINE SCHEMA MY_SCHEMA
(
 COLUMN1 VARCHAR(24),
 COLUMN2 VARCHAR(24),
 LOB_COLUMN1 CLOB,
 LOB_COLUMN1 CLOB,
); 

I have noticed that no temporary files are created if lengths are specified for the CLOB columns that are not too long. For example:
DEFINE SCHEMA MY_SCHEMA
(
 COLUMN1 VARCHAR(24),
 COLUMN2 VARCHAR(24),
 LOB_COLUMN1 CLOB(100000),
 LOB_COLUMN1 CLOB(100000),
); 

In my case, the total length of characters that could be read in was a value between 500,000 and 600,000. My question is: which factor determines the number of characters that can be transferred via ODBC without the creation of temporary files for CLOB columns?

When you don't define a length for the CLOB column, Teradata will handle the data as large objects (LOBs), and since LOBs can be extremely large, the system creates temporary files to store and manage them during the transfer.
When you define a length for the CLOB (e.g., CLOB(100000)), you're telling Teradata that the maximum size of the CLOB column is limited to 100,000 characters, allowing Teradata to handle it more efficiently without needing to create temporary files. The absence of these files makes the process faster because the system doesn't need to deal with external storage for these large objects.
The key factor determining whether temporary files are created is the size of the CLOB data. If the data size exceeds a certain threshold, Teradata will use temporary files to store the data before inserting it into the destination table. By limiting the size with CLOB(length), you control how much data can be transferred directly without needing temporary storage.
ODBC uses buffers to transfer data between systems. If the CLOB data fits within the available buffer size, the transfer can proceed without creating temporary files. When the data exceeds the buffer capacity, the system offloads it to temporary files. The buffer size depends on the ODBC driver settings and the available memory on the system running the transfer.
Some Teradata configurations or settings in your TPT script (like the VARCHAR or CLOB definition) may impact how LOBs are handled. Specifying a reasonable length for the CLOB fields ensures that the data can be transferred without exceeding the system's limits, thus avoiding the creation of temporary files.
I recommend:

Try to define a specific length for the CLOB column that is large enough to accommodate most of your data but not so large that it causes the creation of temporary files. In your case, since the total length is between 500,000 and 600,000 characters, you can define the CLOB length accordingly (e.g., CLOB(600000)).
Check your ODBC driver settings to ensure that buffer sizes are configured optimally for handling large data transfers. Increasing the buffer size might help transfer larger CLOBs without temporary files.
If the size of the CLOB data varies greatly, you may need to experiment with different lengths to find the optimal point where the data is transferred efficiently.

-----the main factor is the size of the CLOB data. Specifying a length that matches or slightly exceeds your typical data size (like CLOB(600000) in your case) should help reduce or eliminate the creation of temporary files during the transfer process.

See also the documentation https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_Lake_VMware/Teradata-Parallel-Transporter-Reference-20.00/Advanced-Database-Considerations/Large-Objects/Moving-LOB-Data-from-an-External-Database-Table-to-a-Database-Table https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_Lake_VMware/Teradata-Parallel-Transporter-Reference-20.00/Advanced-Database-Considerations/Large-Objects/Enhanced-LOB-Support. If the maximum possible total length of a record is under 1MB, data can be sent inline.
